# pygraphviz: How to avoid TypeError: 'NoneType'?

Tags: python, typeerror, pygraphviz

I installed pygraphviz using pip installer and used the first code example from their [projects tutorial page](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) to check if everything works:

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
G = pgv.AGraph()
```

However, I get this error message and can't figure out why:

```
Exception ignored in: <function AGraph.__del__ at 0x7f8#some_more_signs...>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/USER/.conda/envs/Test_Project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 293, in __del__
File "/Users/USER/.conda/envs/Test_Project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1010, in _close_handle
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I also tried deinstalling pygraphviz and reinstall using:

```
conda install --channel conda-forge pygraphviz
```

but ending up getting the same result.